# What is wrong with my function that is supposed to split an array into smaller arrays and put them back into the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code. I modify it for at least 5 times, and the result returned is 0. Weird.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  
  var array=[];
  for(var i=0;i<=arr.length;i=i+size){
    if(i+size<arr.length) array=arr.slice(i,i+size).push();
    else if(i+size>=arr.length) array=arr.slice(i).push();
  }
  
  return array;
}

chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

What should be returned is [[a,b],[c,d]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look more closely at your code:

```
array=arr.slice(i,i+size).push()
```

You're assigning the result of `arr.slice.push` to `array`; but [`push` returns the length of the new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). What you probably really want to be doing is pushing to `array` the slice:

```
array.push(arr.slice(i,i+size))
```

You might then wonder why the ultimate result is `0` and not `2`, which is what you would expect the length of the chunk to be. This is because you're iterating a bit too far; `i<=arr.length` should be `i<arr.length`.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var array=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + size) {
    if (i + size < arr.length) array.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
    else if (i + size >= arr.length) array.push(arr.slice(i));
  }
  
  return array;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
```

Comment: Love it. This is the only answer that doesnt just give a completely new code.

Comment: Should have read the MDN again to renew my knowledge of push.

Comment: I guess it must have taken you some time to go through my algorithm. Like I don't even want to look through my own nasty stuff.

Answer (score 1):

easier to build up chunks...

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  
  var array=[];
  var chunk =[]
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(chunk.length == size) chunk =[]
    if(i%size == 0) array.push(chunk)         
    chunk.push(arr[i]);        
  }      
  return array;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var len = arr.length;
  
  // the number of expected subarrays
  var count = (len % size == 0)? len / size: Math.floor(len / size) + 1;
  
  var array = []
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    // get the propper sub array (slice do check for boundaries so no need to check it ourselves)
    array.push(arr.slice(i * size, (i + 1) * size));
  
  return array;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], 2));
```